# Execute permission denied when many request on ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I currently have a problem with my application. When there are many requests on ASP.NET page which providing data from MS SQL Server database, sometimes .NET throws `SQLException` - execute permission denied on stored procedure xxx, which indicates that user in role don't have permission to execute procedure, but he has and this happens only sometimes when there are many requests.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that's the actual exception and not a deadlock? have you been able to reproduce the exception in your testing environment?

Comment: Well, it's only read operation. I can reproduce this in my testing environment, but i find out, that exception is thrown only if user is logged in, so i think there is some error in my kernel. But don't know, why execution permission denied exception was thrown. (Example: 10 users (in one database role) call method GetAllSupplements, 2 get exception).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Database module must be set before each execution procedure in sequence, not only at start.